# Adding annotations using plot_ly in R for multiple categorical variables to determine x coordinate

Tags: r, plotly, visualization

I am having issues with printing the annotation just outside each bar using the plotly package in R. The problem is arising because I have 2 categorical variables. How do I place the label just on the outside of each bar? I am looking for a dynamic solution as the number of x variables and also the second categorical variable can vary.

[image]

My code:

```
my_chart <- plot_ly(
  x = ~data$categoricalvar1,
  y = ~data$percent_change,
  type = "bar",
  color = ~nutrient_plot_data$categoricalvar2,  #
  colors = c("#256fc0","#ffcc00","#a7d0eb"),  
) %>%
  layout(
    title = paste0("My chart"),
    yaxis = list(title = "% change"),
    xaxis = list(title = ""),
    showlegend = FALSE,
    margin = list(t = 50, b = 100)  
  ) %>%
  add_annotations(
    x = ~data$nutrient, 
    y = ~data$percent_change,
    text =  ~paste0(round(data$percent_change, 2), "%"),
    showarrow = FALSE
  )
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?